# How can I know how many real roots this polynomial has?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Let $x^7-10x^5+15x+5$ a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. I would like to know how many real roots this polynomial has?

I know we have to use the intermediate value theorem, but I don't know how to use in this case in particular.

I need help please.

Thanks

Comment: A strong tool is [Sturm Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Maesumi yes, really powerful.

Comment: Sturm is really powerful, but requires a lot of polynomial division. Using synthetic division, it's not too bad.

Comment: @HenryB. What is synthetic division?

Comment: @Rafael Chavez: It's a way of doing polynomial division that minimizes the number of things you have to write down and keep track of.  I mostly learned how to do it via Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20210404042023/http://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Ecs577/handouts/polyroots.pdf) will work for you.

Uses Descartes’ rules of sign of the Sturm’s Theorem

Comment: I'm going to see this tomorrow, it seems this Sturm's Theorem is really powerful, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: The link had gone dead; I replaced it by an archived version. (This shows why answers that only/mostly consist of links are discouraged.)

Answer (score 2):

The most direct method that I can currently think of is the following:

Differentiate the polynomial, and make a substitution $w=x^2$. This gives us $$7w^3-50w^2+15,$$ a cubic equation in $w$. There is a general formula for solving for the zeroes of a cubic equations, hence we can find the exact roots of this equation, and in turn, we can find the exact roots of $f'(x)$, which tells us where local max/min occur. Checking the values of the function at these points will tell us how many zeroes the polynomial has.

This is a little bit of a long method and probably not the cleanest; I'll see if I can think of a simpler method, but this is certainly one approach to the problem.

Comment: How did you arrive at this cubic equation in $w$?

Comment: $f'(x)=7x^6-50x^4+15$. Substitute $w=x^2$ and we have a cubic polynomial.

Comment: @Clayton can you please tell the general formula for solving for the zeroes if a cubing equation ? I hope it is not the one which is mentioned here http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polyroots.pdf

Comment: @Rahul: That is the correct technique.

Answer (score 2):

We use the [rational roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which says a root of $$f(x) = x^7 -10x^5+15x+5$$ must be an integer that divides $5$, so immediately we have four possibilities: $\pm 1$ or $\pm 5$.  Plugging these into the polynomial we see that $$f(-5) = -46495 \neq 0\\f(-1) = -1 \neq 0 \\f(1) = 11 \neq 0\\f(5) = 46955 \neq 0$$And from this, we see that $f$ has no roots over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: yes, thank you for your answer, but the roots are real. This Polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein theorem, it can't have roots over $\mathbb Q$ as you said.

Comment: The OP has asked about REAL roots.

Answer (score 1):

Using Descartes' rule of signs, we count the number of sign changes.  There are two so there are either two positive root or no positive roots.  Since, $f(0)=5$ and $f(2)=-157$, we know there is at least one positive root, so there must be two.  Further, by examining the transformed polynomial $(-x)^7-10(-x)^5+15(-x)+5 = -x^7+10x^5-15x+5$, we can conclude there are three sign changes and thus either three negative roots or just one.  Note that, $f(-1)=-1$ and $f(-2)=167$. So, we can conclude that there are at least two sign changes in $f$ meaning the number of negative roots must be three, not one.  We can stop here.  Although, we can note that the polynomial tends to negative infinity for large $x$ as the $x^7$ term comes to dominate.  Therefore, we could have concluded there are three sign changes in the value of $f$ and three roots without using the information from Descartes.

Comment: I failed to understand why positive roots either 2 or 0 and not 1? Same for negative.. Thanks in advance. :)